# How to calculate two adjacent values using Python

Tags: python, difference

If I have some code like this below, it will return several values of x. So from this, how can I calculate the difference between all the two adjacent values of x?

```
y = 0.1
while y <=1:
    y += 0.01
    x = y**2
    print(x)
```

Comment: Define adjacent? Is `x` a number or a list?

Comment: Ops, x is a number. By adjacent I mean x - (x-1), (x-1) - (x-2) and so on. Just the difference between the actual value and its next.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty straight forward, the only trick is getting the numbers to start with:

Pythons [`range` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) doesn't accept floats, so we fudge it like so:

```
ys = [y*0.01 for y in range(10,100,1)]
```

From that lets generate all our `xs` from our list of `ys`:

```
xs = [y**2 for y in ys]
```

Now we need to get all the `x` and `x-1`s, this is easy with list slicing and the [`zip` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
adjacents = zip(xs[:-1],xs[1:])
```

Lastly, unpack the tuples and subtract them to get the difference of the adjacent values:

```
diffs = [b-a for a,b in adjacents]
```

You can even do this on one line:

```
diffs = [((y+1)*0.01)**2 - (y*0.01)**2 for y in range(10,100,1)]
```